# PyTorch model expects objects on CPU despite being on GPU

Tags: pytorch

I have a PyTorch Model that I've sent to my device (a GPU on GCS):

```
dnn_regressor = DNNRegressor(n_feature=dataset.X.shape[1], 
                         n_hidden=512, 
                         n_hidden_layers=5,
                         batch_norm=True,
                         n_output=1).to(device)
```

similarly, before training I have sent my (batched) data to the GPU as well. However, when I optimize the model, it appears not to be associated with the GPU:

```
     17         X_batch, y_batch = X_batch.to(device), y_batch.to(device)
     18 
---> 19         prediction = dnn_regressor(X_batch)     # input x and predict based on x

RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #4 'mat1'
```

I'm sure I've done something obviously wrong, but I can't see what it might be.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to relate to how I was constructing the model. I naively thought that I could keep my layers in a list (so that I could generate them programmatically). It turns out that I need to use a `torch.nn.ModuleList` instead, or they don't appear to be added to the model. Not exactly sure why this results in the model not being sent to the GPU, but using `ModuleList`s fixes the problem.